# ElasticSearch 5.x Sorting on Text Field Issue

Tags: sorting, search, elasticsearch, types, mapping

I understand that this is a new change, but I can't see what's wrong with this mapping. This is taken from the mapping of the field registered in ElasticSearch through _mapping call:

```
"key": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
}
```

When I sort using the "key" field, I get this exception. I have also tried adding fieldData=true, but that also didn't work.

```
Caused by: RemoteTransportException[[_6qwpaI][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [key] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.];
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [key] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType.fielddataBuilder(TextFieldMapper.java:335)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.getForField(QueryShardContext.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.FieldSortBuilder.build(FieldSortBuilder.java:281)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortBuilder.buildSort(SortBuilder.java:151)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:678)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:536)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:502)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:243)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService.lambda$registerRequestHandler$6(SearchTransportService.java:276)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$6.doRun(TransportService.java:550)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:527)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

At first I thought this might be related to the use of a field (e.g. key.keyword), but since I'm not doing that, then I don't see any reason why this is not working.

I'm pretty new to ElasticSearch 5.x and the document is contradicting itself so I hope someone can point me to the right direction. This is what I referring to:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

I'm essentially trying to achieve the same as this original mapping that was working until 5.x:

```
"mapping": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "english": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "english"
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, I think the keyword field is auto generated since I didn't even define it in my mapping.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing a similar problem :(

Comment: Take a look at the answer below to see if it helps your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this settings instead for 5.x. "keyword" is the new type for not-analyzed string.

```
{
   "mappings": {
     "doc": {
       "dynamic_templates": [
         {
           "strings": {
             "match_mapping_type": "string",
             "mapping": {
               "type": "text",
               "fields": {
                 "raw": {
                   "type": "keyword",
                   "ignore_above": 256
                 },
                 "english": {
                   "type": "text",
                   "analyzer": "english"
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   }
 }
```

Here's the explanation I got from Lee Hinman in ElasticSearch forum.

> If you index a string with no mapping, ES in 5.0+ now automatically
>   creates a text version and a keyword version (under .keyword) of the
>   field.

This is actually rather confusing some match_mapping_type doesn't understand value "text".

> There's a disconnect for this, the "dynamic" type used for
>   match_mapping_type is the type of the field, not necessarily the ES
>   type. For instance, match_mapping_type only supports "long", not
>   "integer" because it maps to the data type rather than an ES type. So
>   even though ES itself uses "text" and "keyword", the data type is
>   still a "string".
>
> I agree this is confusing, there was a PR here:
>   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17285 for 5.0+ that adds
>   deprecation logging for this, and I opened
>   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/22090 so 6.0 will throw
>   an exception when an unrecognized type is used.